# Ui elements not scaling correctly

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a mobile game with Unity. When you win or die in the game you get this screen, most of the game we have developed with the resolution set to a 18:9 aspect ratio and it always scaled properly over to 16:9.

However just recently when switching to 16:9 the button's get all squished like this. The canvas scaling is set to match witdth/height and set to 0.5 at 2160x1080. How can we fix this.

Thanks in advance,

Roan van der Duim.

[image]

Comment: Your buttons' `RectTransfrom`'s anchors are not properly set.

Comment: From what i can tell they are set correctly to each corner off the button.

Comment: If the triangle wedges are not all in the same spot (i.e. each corner of the button as you have said) then that means that the object will scale in proportion to its parent being scaled. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I put all the anchors in the middle at one spot and now they work. I have one more question though: why are the text elements and sprites in the main game ui scaling correctly why all the elements in the panel scale like this?

Comment: Text doesn't scale the same way as other objects. It will never squash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477492/unity-4-6-how-to-scale-gui-elements-to-the-right-size-for-every-resolution

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to set the canvas scaler to Scale with Screen Size. I don't know if you already have it set to scale with screen size, otherwise you just need to adjust the anchors of your UI objects. Hope it helps.